# Adding some Regex code to my Ruby webscraper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm building a webscraper and using Nokogiri. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'



class Scraper

  def get_page
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.theskimm.com/recent"))
    h = {}
    doc.xpath('//a[@href]').each do |link|   
      h[link.text.strip] = link['href']
    end
    puts h
  end
  binding.pry
end

Scraper.new.get_page
```

This returns me a hash of all URLs on the page (I only pasted the first few lines):

```
{"Back to Sign Up"=>"/", "SHARE THIS"=>"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theskimm.com%2F2015%2F12%2F07%2Fskimm-for-december-8th-2&display=popup", "theSkimm\nSkimm for December 8th"=>"/", "Trump campaign press release"=>"http://skimmth.is/1SKR0bP", "assault weapons ban"=>"http://skimmth.is/1QbnCO8"}
```

However, I'd like to only grab the URLs that contain "http://skimmth.is/" as part of the value. What code/ Regular Expression would I need to add to my original Scraper class to ONLY selects URLs with that address?

Comment: `h[link.text.strip] = link['href'] if link['href'] =~ /http:\/\/skimmth.is\//`

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` as a statement modifier to check that the value is appropriate before adding it to the hash.  For example, update this line:

```
h[link.text.strip] = link['href']
```

to

```
h[link.text.strip] = link['href'] if link['href'] =~ /http:\/\/skimmth.is\//
```

FWIW: [`=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) is the match method for the `Regexp` class.

Comment: It's actually a method, though. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains()` function of xpath.

```
doc.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "http://skimmth.is/")]').map{|e| e.attr(:href)}

=> ["http://skimmth.is/1SKR0bP",
 "http://skimmth.is/1QbnCO8",
 "http://skimmth.is/1SHBSff",
 "http://skimmth.is/1N8dORo",
 "http://skimmth.is/1HRwGoO",
 "http://skimmth.is/1HRmEUG",
 "http://skimmth.is/1NePsmI",
 "http://skimmth.is/1IQoJLn",
 "http://skimmth.is/1ToQ6T1",
 "http://skimmth.is/1IAZ6mW",
 "http://skimmth.is/1N7Foy1",
 "http://skimmth.is/1m7B6Op",
 "http://skimmth.is/1SKBhJW",
 "http://skimmth.is/1ToQ6T1",
 "http://skimmth.is/1XfpwkX%20",
 "http://skimmth.is/1P9rq20"]
```